# chess game online: how to design the server

Tags: multithreading, sockets, serversocket

I'm developing a chess game online.

My idea is to make the server as the place where the data communicate from one player to the other.

So here is my plan to continue:
When two players connect the server(with TCP), the server create two threads for both of them. It means that the two threads need to communicate each other.

```
// server
while(true)
{
    if(socket.accept())
    {
        create_a_thread(); // handle one player
    }
}
```

But one game needs two threads in the server? I don't think this is a good design.

How should I redesign my server?

Comment: You're right. A thread per connection is usually a bad idea - which is especially two under higher loads (the context switches start to become more and more expensive). Have a look at the reactor pattern and read over [Beej's guide](http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/).

Comment: P.S. Consider existing frameworks or libraries if you have a specific language in mind. I have a friend that wrote [an amazing variation on the classic chess game](http://www.secretchess.com) and the server was written using node.js, which is single threaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two thoughts on the conceptual layer:

- Are you sure you want to have all users go through your server? Why not do some peer-to-peer between two players?!
- When going through a central server, you don't need a 1-1 "relation" between two players. Your server could introduce an API like `makeMove(Game g, Move m)` where one player just pushes the move to the server, and the server then sends a notification to that **one** client.

What I mean is: it is important to keep things as simple as possible. When you build a mental model of a chess game; yes, then the first idea is that even your server would need that notion of a "game" of "two connected" users. But that isn't necessarily true. Rather see the server as a "mail box" where you put a letter "here is my next move"; and the server makes sure it gets to the other player!

Long story short: you should first identify the **core** responsibilities within your server (like: "receiving user requests", "processing user requests", "send notifications"); and then you look into "multi-threading" those.

Comment: Many thanks. I don't quite understand how p2p works. If I'm right, p2p is to make one player as a server and the other as the client so that they can communicate without my server's help. But I'm considering that this might be risk. If the server player is `accept`ing while a hacker is scanning his ports... Is this a possibility? If not, could you give me some guide about the architecture of p2p?

Comment: You still have a server for the p2p solution: your peers connect to the server; and say "I want to play"; and then the server selects two clients that **then** get each others IP and start talking to each other. But beware: this is not a free service were we do a complete design for you.